# Is it sensible to calculate posterior by dividing histograms?

Tags: bayesian, histogram

I have some data I want to classify as $A$ or $\bar{A}$ (not-$A$) based on two metric features $M$ and $P$. It seems straight-forward to calculate a posterior probability, that a given combination of $M$ and $P$ exhibits $A$, simply by dividing histograms. Is this a sensible way to do this?

I calculated a large number of samples, and divided them into one set of all values, and one (sub)set of only the values that exhibit $A$. Then I calculate

- a 2D (density) histogram of the first sample set, and interpret it as the marginal likelihood $p(M,P)$;
- a 2D (density) histogram of the second sample set, and interpret it as the likelihood $p(M,P|A)$;
- the ratio of the number of samples in each sample set, and interpret it as the prior $p(A)$

From that, I derive the posterior by 
$$ p(A|M,P) = \frac{ p(M,P|A) \cdot p(A) }{ p(M,P) } 
$$
for every bin in the histograms. Both histograms use the same bin edges.

Looking at the result, this seems to yield reasonable results (i.e. regions of high $M$ *and* low $P$ have a high posterior probability around $1$, while the rest has a low posterior probability around $0$). Of course the resulting 2D posterior is noisy, but that can be mitigated by calculating more samples, excluding barely-supported values, and smoothing.

However, this procedure seems overly simplistic and not very "scientific". Is this a sensible procedure, or is there a better way?